# Word Outliner - How to collapse all the text that is NOT marked red?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, outline

I am using the word 2010 Outliner to write paper. As I am currently working on it, I am putting all my sources in my outline. However, some sources have to be researched further. Therefore, I am currently marking them red.

Any recommendation how to display all red marked nodes in the outliner or search for them?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: @Raystafarian I have researched, but haven't found anything related to my problem. An idea(were I haven't found anything yet) is to create a macro to show all relevant parts, but I am a newbie in macro creation and therefore my question here.

Answer (score 3):

Searching for them is easy and relatively straightforward, even if not immediately obvious.

Ctrl-F will open the Find pane & then you can get to the dialog by clicking thus:

[image: Advanced Find]

Then you'll get this dialog:

[image: Dialog]

Click the More >> button

[image: More]

Click on the Format button, choose Font and then select the color you want to search for (i.e., Red)

[image]

Click OK. Now the Red attribute appears:

[image: Red]

Click Find Next & you're in business!